# Split the dates which is rolling past 00:00 hrs into two rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-stage

I want to split a single row into multiple rows based on time at 00:00:00 hrs in snowflake. below are the example.
StartDate and EndDate is in Timestamp_NTZ(9) datatype.

| SrNo | NotificateDate | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-08-20 | 2018-08-20 07:27:00.000 | 2018-08-21 16:23:00.000 |
| 2 | 2018-08-21 | 2018-08-21 03:36:00.000 | 2018-08-21 04:36:00.000 |
| 3 | 2018-08-21 | 2018-08-21 04:36:00.000 | 2018-08-21 21:35:00.000 |

Expected output is below:

| SrNo | NotificationDate | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-08-20 | 2018-08-20 07:27:00.000 | 2018-08-20 23:59:59.000 |
| 2 | 2018-08-21 | 2018-08-21 00:00:00.000 | 2018-08-21 16:23:00.000 |
| 3 | 2018-08-21 | 2018-08-21 03:36:00.000 | 2018-08-21 04:36:00.000 |
| 4 | 2018-08-21 | 2018-08-21 04:36:00.000 | 2018-08-21 21:35:00.000 |

I need to split on the next day 00:00:00 hrs if the time is overlapping to the next day

I tried to find the date diff between  the startdate and enddate but doesnt work as expected.

Comment: In your first table you have two columns called StartDate

Comment: Updated the column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it covers all scenarios, I tried to make a condition comparing the day part in endDate and StartDate columns:

Try this:

```
WITH
  original AS (
    SELECT 
        startdate,
        enddate
    FROM times --replace with the name of your table
  ),
  before_midnight AS (
    SELECT   
        startdate, 
        CASE 
          WHEN DATE_PART('DAY', StartDate) < DATE_PART('DAY', EndDate) THEN
            DATEADD('second', -1, TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE (EndDate)))
          ELSE enddate
        END AS enddate
    FROM original
  ),
  after_midnight AS (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
          WHEN DATE_PART('DAY', StartDate) < DATE_PART('DAY', EndDate) THEN
            TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(enddate))
          ELSE startdate
        END AS startdate,
        enddate 
    FROM original
  )
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY startDate) AS SrNo,
    DATE(startDate) AS NotificationDate,
    startDate,
    endDate 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM before_midnight
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT * FROM after_midnight
) AS combined
ORDER BY startDate;
```

Comment: Yet to validate but looks promising

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like:

A CTE with the example data:

```
with example_data(SrNo, NotificateDate, StartDate, EndDate) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2018-08-20'::date, '2018-08-20 07:27:00.000'::timestamp, '2018-08-21 16:23:00.000'::timestamp),
    (2, '2018-08-21'::date, '2018-08-21 03:36:00.000'::timestamp, '2018-08-21 04:36:00.000'::timestamp),
    (3, '2018-08-21'::date, '2018-08-21 04:36:00.000'::timestamp, '2018-08-21 21:35:00.000'::timestamp)
)
```

and then enrich that to find the steps of days in each window:

```
), enrich as (
    select *,
        datediff('day', StartDate, EndDate) as steps
    from example_data
)
```

and then a block of "row numbers" to do date shifting by, this you want the 5 to be the biggest number span you expect in the data you have

```
), max_span as (
    select row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn
    from table(generator(rowcount=>5))
)
```

then you mix them together:

```
select a.srno
    ,a.NotificateDate
    ,r.rn
    ,a.StartDate
    ,dateadd('day', r.rn, a.StartDate) as day_start_plus_rn
    ,date_trunc('day', day_start_plus_rn) as trunc_day_start
    ,greatest(a.StartDate, trunc_day_start) as row_start
    ,dateadd('day', r.rn+1, a.StartDate) as day_end_plus_rn
    ,date_trunc('day', day_end_plus_rn) as trunc_day_end
    ,least(a.EndDate, trunc_day_end)
from enrich as a
left join max_span as r
    on r.rn <= a.steps
order by 1,2,3
```

[image]

but now having shown how it works can be compressed down to:

```
with enrich as (
    select *,
        datediff('day', StartDate, EndDate) as steps
    from example_data
), max_span as (
    select row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn
    from table(generator(rowcount=>5))
)
select
    a.srno
    ,a.NotificateDate
    --,r.rn
    ,greatest(a.StartDate, date_trunc('day', dateadd('day', r.rn, a.StartDate))) as row_start
    ,least(a.EndDate, date_trunc('day', dateadd('day', r.rn+1, a.StartDate))) as row_end
from enrich as a
left join max_span as r
    on r.rn <= a.steps
order by 1,2,r.rn
```

giving

[image]

I see the end-time is truncated so you can use BETWEEN, which makes some sense, it is more performant over independent date compares, but to exclude the end time I prefer the form

```
WHERE a.time between b.start_time and b.end_time 
   AND a.time < b.end_time
```

which is our years of testing was as fast as the BETWEEN but avoids have the end_time needing to be millisecond correct, which your examples are not.

But if you really want the time you wish

```
,least(a.EndDate, dateadd('second', -1, date_trunc('day', dateadd('day', r.rn+1, a.StartDate)))) as row_end
```

will give the results you want:

[image]